# Monthly date tree

Tags: org-capture

I'd like to use datetree with month (alternatively week) granularity. Currently the datetree looks like that:

```
* 2019
** 2019-03 March
*** 2019-03-17 Sunday
**** TODO Weekly review
```

I'd like to drop the level 3 -- day, and how something like that:

```
* 2019
** 2019-03 March
*** TODO Weekly review
```

I've looked at https://orgmode.org/manual/Template-elements.html and it doesn't seem this is a build-in feature. Can you suggest any workaround how to achieve such a simplified datetree?

There is a similar question on the orgmode mailing list http://lists.gnu.org/archive/html/emacs-orgmode/2018-02/msg00092.html but without any answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Defining the following function should help:

```
(defun org-find-month-in-datetree()
  (org-datetree-find-date-create (calendar-current-date))
  (kill-line))
```

Then use an org-capture template like this:

```
'(org-capture-templates
  (quote
   ("w" "Weekly review" plain
    (file+function "~/org/test.org" org-find-month-in-datetree)
    "*** TODO Weekly review\n%?"                ;;\n for newline
 ))))
```

To get the same for a weekly date-tree change the function to

```
(defun org-find-week-in-datetree()
  (org-datetree-find-iso-week-create (calendar-current-date))
  (kill-line))
```

Comment: Since the original question (Mar 2019!) and now I've switched to use an online service for my tasks :) I don't have an org mode configured anymore to test, but would it work if there are some days under given month? the `kill-line` will drop only the most recent day right? Anyways, seems like a good way if you don't want days at all (this is what I've wanted in the past) -- I'm going to accept :) Welcome to the forum and a good first contribution!

Comment: It works for me. Only the current day's heading is replaced if it exists. Subheadings of the current day's heading are not replaced, if they exist, though. How would I enalble a prompt for the day like `:time-prompt t`?